# MS Access SQL: Count of records with duplicate PersonID & EventID values based on Status value

Tags: sql, ms-access

These values are records in a single table. I'm trying to pull some records where an individual (PersonID) can be in the same course (EventID) multiple times with different status (Status).  For example, PersonID=123456 can have multiple rows of EventID=ACT123.  The Status is different on every row, with values of 'A', 'W', or 'D'.  What I want to have is a count of PersonID where they have records with Status of 'A' and 'D' in the same event (EventID).  For example:

PersonID = 786156, EventID = ACT123, Status = A
PersonID = 786156, EventID = ACT123, Status = D
PersonID = 685234, EventID = ACT123, Status = A
PersonID = 685234, EventID = ACT789, Status = D

So PersonID 786156 would be selected but PersonID 685234 wouldn't.  Any suggestions?
*edited to add examples*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select personID, eventID
from mytable
where status in ('A', 'D')
group by personID, eventID
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Based on the description, I think `count(distinct)` is more appropriate.

Comment: I think my initial description wasn't clear enough.  I've added some examples of the records I want to select and those I want to exclude.

Comment: @HansUp Yeah, this is on me.  Initially when I put in code, I got results that didn't have Status=D values.  After seeing your comment I tried it again and looked a little closer at the results.  I think I got the results I did because there are some records where the record: "PersonID = 786156, EventID = ACT123, Status = A" exists twice because it has two different meeting locations.  I don't need the meeting location information, so I might have to recreate my dataset to ensure the records aren't duplicated